# Gallery not showing in SimpleModal in ie8

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I'm trying to get a pop-up window to display a simple gallery on our new site.

I'm using SimpleModal for the pop-up and Ad-Gallery for the slide show.

It all works fine in firefox, chrome etc but in internet explorer the winow pops up ok but the gallery wont work unless you right click on the iframe and click refresh at which point everything works fine. I've spent a couple of days searching for an answer without any luck can anyone please help? The code for opening the pop-up is...

```
         <div id="content">
      <div id='basic-modal'>
        <div>
        <a href="#" id="tours_past_gallery_link" name='list' class='list'><i>Gallery of past tours</i></a>
        </div>
         <div id="list-modal-content">
         <iframe width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="tours_gallery.html"></iframe>
         </div>
        <!-- preload the images -->
        <div style='display:none'>
        <img src='img/basic/x.png' alt='' />
        </div>
      </div id='basic-modal'>
     </div id="content">
```

thank you